# Update table using select query

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-update

I'm trying to update `desiredValue` from `updatedTable` table if only the statements from where clause is satisfied, otherwise it should not set a value. Is below a correct statement?

```
 update updatedTable si  
 set desiredValue = select desiredValue
                    from otherTable sl 
                    where sl.att1 = si.att1 and sl.att2 = si.att2;
```

Comment: DBMS name please

Comment: postgresql is used

Comment: `Is below a correct statement`-- Yes its correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like below:

```
UPDATE updatedTable
set updatedTable.desiredValue = otherTable.desiredValue
FROM otherTable
WHERE updatedTable.att1 = otherTable.att1 and updatedTable.att2 = otherTable.att2
```